# Fade black overlay on text

Tags: css, animation, display

I'm trying to create a transparent overlay on a div containing text. It should animate on and off when triggered via a button. Normally you can just create a div inside that div with absolute positioning and full width/height, changing the opacity using an ease or animation ([Black transparent overlay on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526307/black-transparent-overlay-on-image)).

But I want to be able to select the text in the div. Changing the overlay from

```
display: block
```

to

```
display: none
```

Will break the fading animation. How do I fade from block to none, so I can re-use my underlaying div?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please clarify a bit. What is meant by _"re-using my underlying div?"_ If you're triggering the animation from a button, why do you need to use `display`? Why won't animating `opacity` work?

Comment: You can go down the opacity road like you mentioned in your question and just add pointer-events: none; and pointer-events: all;  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, this might be what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popupbtn").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".overlay").css("display","block");
  });
  $("#close").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);
    //$(".overlay").css("display","none");
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: RGBa(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}
.popup {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="popupbtn">click me</button>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <p>popup text</p>
    <button id="close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation: after `$(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);` is completed, then the `display: block` CSS will come in.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can go down the opacity road like you mentioned in your question and just add `pointer-events: none;` and `pointer-events: all;`. The pointer-events property tells the browser how that element should react to mouse and touch interactions, if you set it to "none" it just let's the events through, like the element wasn't even there. More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

The browser support is decent (except ie<10, but there's a polyfill somewhere on github) http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $('.container').toggleClass('overlay-open');
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay-open .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle Overlay</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="back">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi ipsam, illum sed dolorum quos modi, quibusdam cum tempora molestias laboriosam voluptas. Fuga corporis earum modi, aut nisi in molestias explicabo voluptatem iure distinctio tempora, iusto doloremque. Inventore culpa eligendi dolore. Expedita, officia, assumenda. Id magnam molestias saepe, cupiditate, architecto autem.
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```